# Multiple variable types incorporated with int variable

Tags: c#

I have the below code for a simple console application in C#. Whenever I input the AIR rate for the second input I get "input string was not in correct format" as the error. What is the correct format and how do I incorporate it into the current code I have made? I am not familiar with different variable types.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int AIR, MIR, PMT, IP, PP, ABorrowed, Term;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount borrowed on your loan ");
            ABorrowed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the interest rate for your loan ");
            AIR = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter term of your loan in months ");
            Term = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            MIR = AIR / 1200;

            PMT = ABorrowed * (MIR/1-(1/(1+MIR)^Term));

            IP = ABorrowed * MIR;

            PP = PMT - IP;

            Console.WriteLine("Your total payment for this month is "+PMT);
            Console.WriteLine("Of that payment " + IP + " is interest rate");
            Console.WriteLine("and the Payment Portion is " + PP);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what exactly are you entering?

Comment: You'll want to get familiar with _integer division_ sooner than later.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but you'll want to look at your `PMT =` line, as well.  ^ doesn't mean "to the power of" - it does a "bitwise or".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the correct format and how do I incorporate it into the current code I have made?

The problem is that you haven't entered an integer on the command line.

We can't really tell any more than that, as you haven't specified what you *are* writing... but if you just write something as simple as "100" it should be fine (as far as that error is concerned).

I'd *strongly* advise you to use `camelCase` for your local variables though, declare them at the point of first use (rather than all at the top of the method), and give them more meaningful names - such as `monthlyPayment` instead of `PMT`. As IronMan84 says, you might also want to use `decimal` for any currency values, although I guess at the level of mortgages, the cents are unlikely to make much difference. Using `decimal` for the interest rate would make a lot of sense though.

Comment: To be honest, I've done 3 separate courses on programming in 3 separate schools, they all told us to declare all variables at the top of the code. I don't do it anymore, but if OP is still learning/taking courses, odds are he is being instructed to do so :-)

Comment: @Flater: Anyone importing language habits from one language to another (some laanguages *required* this, or at least did) should be told off. Anyone doing so *in an educational capacity* should think very carefully about the impact they can have on others :(

Comment: I think it's mostly taught so students don't run wild with the amount of variables they declare. I suspect it also helps with keeping a consistent naming to your variables. Didn't work on me though, I just started every project with `int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;`, then deleted what was never used. But I'm the kind of coder that only uses good naming because my colleagues ask me to ;)

Comment: To clarify, I did that in school projects that I knew were just create once, run once, never look at it again. KIDS! Please don't code like I just did!

Comment: @Flater: I think it's rather more likely to be for historical reasons. But either way, it's a really bad idea :(

Comment: I agree :) Then again, in console applications under 50 lines, no one should care :)

Comment: @Flater: I care because sloppiness is habit-forming. Best to get people out of the habit as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Interest rates are typically done in the `decimal` or `double` variable types. Trying to do that in an `int` variable will cause these problems.

`int` types are not built to handle decimal values at all. They are meant for storing whole numbers.

Comment: So how would I change it to a double format type without screwing up the rest of my code? I feel like if I change it to double it will screw the rest up.

Comment: Just declare that variable on a separate line. They don't need to all be on the same line.

Comment: Actually, I believe that they all should actually be doubles, if I'm reading what you're trying to do correctly.

Comment: Using `double` would be a *terrible* choice, IMO. For a mortgage, `int` is probably fine - for more detailed values, `decimal` is appropriate. `double` is almost *never* the right type to use for currency values.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I bow to superior knowledge. `decimal` it is.

Answer (score 0):

If the value for AIR var will be i.e. xx.xx, you should use decimal or double type vars.
Also all vars in your application (finantial) should be decimal/double.